# herenow() successCallback returns channel=null

Tags: android, callback, null, pubnub

maybe you have an idea why the successCallback gets a "null" String as the channel name when I call PubNubs hereNow() function:

> HERENOW : SUCCESS on channel null : {"service":"Presence","message":"OK","occupancy":1,"status":200,"uuids":[{"uuid":"507ea4fb-be77-4e05-bdb9-9c5af69e3de7"}]}

I call hereNow like this:

```
pubnub.hereNow("channelname", true, true, hereNowCallBack)
```

With the Callback implemented like this:

```
Callback hereNowCallBack = new Callback(){
        @Override
        public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
            Log.d("PUBNUB","HERENOW : SUCCESS on channel " + channel + " : " + message.toString());             
        }

        @Override
        public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
            Log.d("PUBNUB","HERENOW : ERROR on channel " + channel + " : " + error.toString());}
    };
```

For all the other pubnub functions I do get the correct channel name in the callback functions - hence I wonder if there might be a bug in the pubnub jar? I am using version 3.7.0

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: Matthias, I know you have been in touch with us through support a bit ago about other questions but let me know if you were able to resolve this issue and what that resolution was.

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub Here Now API

Because you are providing the value of the channel in the hereNow method

`pubnub.hereNow("my_channel", callback);`

you already know the value so it is not provided in the Callback.

```
Callback callback = new Callback() {
  public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
    System.out.println(response.toString());
  }
  public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
    System.out.println(error.toString());
  }
};
```

But it can be difficult to tie the data of the call with callback. There are some new features to assist with this in future releases of the SDKs. Your feedback is appreciated and definitely being taken into consideration to make the API easier to use.

[See full PubNub Java SDK docs for hereNow](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/api-reference#here_now) (other SDKs also available).